# Working with v-menu and styles does not work

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working with `vue`, I implemented my menu and everything is fine so far, but now I want to change the color, size, font etc with `css`, searching the web so far nothing has worked for me

```
<v-toolbar-items>
        <v-menu :rounded="rounded" open-on-hover offset-y transition="slide-x-transition" bottom right>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn flat v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> Masterlist </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-list dense>
            <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in Masterlist" :key="index" router :to="item.link">
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
```

That's what I have so far, any way to style my menu?

Comment: is there any problem in defining custom classes on elements and styling them? like: `<v-list-item class="my-list-item" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt, `class` or `style` really didn't work for `v-menu`s. The menu styles are being computed after mounted. You should use `content-class` to set custom styles. Example:

```html
<v-menu content-class="my-class">
    <!--Anything-->
<v-menu>
```